# Keep rows together on the same page in ReportViewer (RDLC)

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer, rdl

I've created a RDLC report that looks like this:
[image]

Basically data is grouped first by `Category` and then by `Subcategory`. Then, as you can see from the screenshot, the `Details` group has multiple rows, since I want to organize data in that "grid-like" layout.

Now, the problem is that I want the following pagination behavior:

- The first row of the table (`[Category]`) should never have a page break after it, in other words: it should always stay together with the second row (`[Subcategory]`)
- Same with the second row (`[Subcategory]`): I never want a page break after it, it should always appear together with the first block of detail rows
- The details rows should never be split into multiple pages, so I want all the 9 table rows in the details group to always appear together on the same page

I've been playing around for several hours with the `KeepTogether` and `KeepWithGroup` properties of the Row and Column groups, but they mostly seem to have no effect whatsoever. How should I set them to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: Do you really need detail grouping on row headers?  It seems like you could remove at least 3 or 4 of those.  I'm not really sure you need any detail groupings, actually... 
 Additionally, check the properties on your groupings.  Do you have any page breaks set in the groups?

Comment: @Steve-o169: forgive me, but I'm not an expert with RDLC, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, which elements should not be grouped?

Comment: Basically, details groups are only necessary when you'll have multiple rows of data from a given set of fields.  You currently have a Details group on header rows that are static.  [img](https://imgur.com/pPVL8mG) in this image, the red circles indicate groupings that are not necessary.  Yellow are rows that could potentially have multiple rows.  It looks like you want to maintain the current grid layout, so I'd personally remove all of the Details grouping.  In the Row Groups panel, just delete everything under Details.  You can always `Control + Z` to undo if it's wrong.

Comment: Also, I should note, you will be given the option to `Delete Rows and Grouping` or `Delete Group Only` or something to that effect.  Choose the option that only deletes the grouping.

Comment: @Steve-o169: thanks for your support. However, I tried removing some of the `(Static)` groupings you mention, but I don't understand how! They don't have a right-click menu and selecting them and pressing "DEL" does nothing... am I missing something obvious? I also tried removing the `(Details)` group entirely, but that just means that I only get the first block of rows for each [Subcategory], basically I'm losing data, so I assume it's not what you meant?

Comment: You should be able to right click the area of the row that I circled in my picture and find something like `Row Group > Delete Group`.

Comment: @Steve-o169: I can, but that deletes the entire `(Details)` group. And if I do this, I only get the first entry for each sub-category, because I'm not "looping through" the detail rows anymore. Basically I'm losing rows...